# How to remove all unique objects using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, unique

Say, I have `LinkedList<T1>` like this:

`{ A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J }`

In this list:

`B.param == C.param == F.param == p1` and `G.param == I.param == p2`, so I have to get next:

`{ B, C, F, G, I }`

Comment: Can you share what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Well, I tried to google it, but all I've found was "how to remove duplicates". Also I watched list of `Enumerable` methods in docs, but I couldn't find appropriate method.

Comment: Is this a `List` or a `LinkedList`? How you are initializing the linked list like this?

Comment: Are you saying that you only want duplicates in your list?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Not like this, I wrote it so to simplify the question.

Comment: FYI what you are doing here could be more clearly described as: I want to partition a list into equivalence classes and filter out the singleton classes.  The equivalence relation you are concerned with here is equality of the param field. However that likely still would not get you good google hits. I should do a blog on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
list = new LinkedList<T1>(
    list
    .GroupBy(x => x.param)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x));
```

You group the items by the `param` property (this is like creating a list of groups, each group contains the items that share the same value of the `param` property).

In your example, this will create 7 groups:

{A}, {B,C,F}, {D}, {E}, {G,I}, {H}, {J}

Then you filter the groups by taking only the groups that have more than one item (and thus remove the groups that have a single item).

When you keep the groups that have more than one item, you keep {B,C,F} and {G,I}.

Then you flatten the groups back into individual items via `SelectMany`, which gives you {B,C,F,G,I}.

**Performance Test:**

If you might have lists that are large, then you should consider performance. The solution that I provide is very efficient, here is how you can test it and compare performance with the other solution:

```
List<T1> list = new List<T1>();

Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    list.Add(new T1 { param = rnd.Next(1,5000).ToString()});
}

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var result1 =
    list
        .GroupBy(x => x.param)
        .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .ToList();

long result1_time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

sw.Restart();

var result2 = list.Where(el => list.Any(z => z.param == el.param && z != el)).ToList();

long result2_time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

Console.WriteLine(result1_time);
Console.WriteLine(result2_time);

Console.ReadLine();
```

On my machine, my solution takes ~3 milliseconds, and the other solution takes ~2500ms.

Comment: Bah, was just about to paste the same thing in, guess I will give you a +1 instead.

Comment: I thought first to group and remove elements with `Count == 1`, but isn't it more efficient to remove unique elements first and then group the rest than group everything and only then remove unique?

Comment: But then you are back to square one. How you are going to remove unique elements?

Comment: What is the size of your list?

Comment: It can be too few or too large. It varies.

Comment: @Necronomicron, I updated my answer with some performance testing

Comment: This is indeed the more performant way to go. However it may be worth noting that this solution trades increased memory use for decreased time. Building the set of groups can be expensive in space if the original sequence is extremely large.

Comment: Good point @EricLippert. I guess in this case OP has to do time and memory measurements to be able to determine what approach to use.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
var b = list.Where(el => list.Any(z => z.param == el.param && z != el));
```